# unable to set a LatLngBounds with longitude from -180 to 0

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

When trying to set a new LatLngBounds, for the southwest quarter of the world, the SouthWest longitude is automatically set at the other side of the world, leading to an unconsistent LatLngBounds (SouthWest is more east than NorthEast)

```
a = new google.maps.LatLng(-90, -180, true);
a.lng();
=> -180
b = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0, true);
c = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(a, b);
c.getSouthWest().lng();
=> 180
```

The problem seems not to be in the LatLng, but more in the LatLngBounds. Are they other params or other ways to do it so it can represent this quarter of the world ?

Tests with more parameters, only southwest longitude is always set to -180 : http://jsfiddle.net/vr6ztq9z/1/

Comment: Have you tried -179.9 (or something slightly less than -180)?

Comment: @geocodezip yes, that would work as expected, but what's the limit ? I's like to be exactly this quarter. For google.maps.LatLng class it says "Longitude ranges between -180 and 180 degrees, inclusive", so I would expect LatLngBounds to be the same. But nothing clear about it.https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds

Comment: You could document the issue and file a report in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/).

Comment: done here https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7383

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Latitude:**

On a Mercator projection, the maximum north latitude is not 90, but something around [85.05113](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection#Truncation_and_aspect_ratio). In JavaScript you can do:

```
Math.atan(Math.sinh(Math.PI)) * 180 / Math.PI;
```

This way you can find the **real north and south edges** of the projection.

**Longitude:**

What's the difference between a longitude of -180 and 180? None.

You can still **identify all 4 quarters of the projection**:

```
var maxLat = Math.atan(Math.sinh(Math.PI)) * 180 / Math.PI;

var center = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
var sw = new google.maps.LatLng(-maxLat, 180);
var ne = new google.maps.LatLng(maxLat, -180);

// Southwest part of the world
new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, center);

// Southeast part of the world
new google.maps.LatLngBounds(center, sw);
```

And so on.

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/urtuoLsp/)</kbd>

Comment: What's the difference between a longitude of -180 and 180? None. I know but google doesn't : bounds.contains(new google.maps.LatLng(-45, -90)) => false

Comment: updated jsfiddle with maxLat value. thanks for the improvement http://jsfiddle.net/vr6ztq9z/3/

Comment: @MrUpsidedown that's what i was about to add, it works on your exemple, not on mine

Comment: The random lat/lng in your fiddle are out of range most of the time. I get stuff like `Lat: -130.59283265147465 Lng: -314.0259689139202`

Comment: Well that might in fact comes from the way I displayed areas : http://jsfiddle.net/urtuoLsp/7/ (please, not the setPolygon function). I guess that it works fine after all.

Comment: I don't know what your last link is supposed to show. Please mark as accepted if it answered your question.

Comment: right, with using the latitude absolute limit, it seems to work. or it always has and I missed it. It doesn't really the question, though the information is quite useful, so I guess I should mark it. thanks.