# add a marker according to Google Api v3 book/also with a button

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markers

I have created a simple button that asks for latitude and longitude and if the users inputs lets say 22,15 a marker should show up but for some reason my code isn't working

the code is:

```
var map;
var marker;
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng();
function initialize() {

var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.4375, 12.3358);
    myOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);

function zoomto() {
    map.set('zoom', parseInt(prompt('zoom value')));
}


function setCentre()
{
    map.setOptions({center: new google.maps.LatLng(prompt("Latitude: "),prompt("Longitude: "))});
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


function Marker1 () {

    map.setOptions({Marker: new google.maps.LatLng(prompt("Latitude: "),prompt("Longitude: "))});
    }
function Marker () {

    map.setOptions({Marker: new google.maps.LatLng(prompt("Latitude: "),prompt("Longitude: "),prompt("Color "),prompt("style "),prompt("number "))});
    }


var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    title: 'Hello World'
});​
```

I have many buttons zoom or move to which both work however I can't get the markers to work.

thanks for looking and help.

Comment: the buttons have not been displayed and the code for the marker: var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: myLatlng,
    title:"Hello World!"
});

Comment: You are not adding a marker at all + you are using undocumented methods + you didn't put any effort in finding how to do what you want.

Comment: I tried to add the whole code but it says there is a problem and it wont let  me do it.  it only recognised the bits i left i have more code but it didn't want to let me post it so i will have to add it to the comments bit by bit.

Comment: `myLatlng` and `myLatLng` are not the same.

Comment: function Marker1 () {
 
    map.setOptions({Marker: new google.maps.LatLng(prompt("Latitude: "),prompt("Longitude: "))});
    } this is the code for the button only thing i to do now is to make it show the marker on the map

Comment: Provide your complete code in the question. A Marker is not a map option. Why don't you start by looking at a **[simple example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple)** and add your own logic later?

Comment: I was able to do the simple marker with the point as position but I need to be able to put a marker wherever the users wants to, that is the harder part and that is why I thought creating a button where they user can input their own  latitude and longitude would solved that problem.

Comment: There are just too many mistakes / incoherences in your code.

Comment: i understand some of these codes but not all of them i been only doing this for 2 weeks and I have been following the book that I was told to follow by my lecturer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to center a map from user input (lat/lng) that includes validation.

It checks whether the lat and lng are valid. More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27115480/1238965) regarding the latitude min/max range.

**HTML**

```
<form id="mapCenterForm">
    Lat:
    <input type="text" id="lat" />
    <br />Lng:
    <input type="text" id="lng" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Center map" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Calculate maximum latitude value on mercator projection
var maxLat = Math.atan(Math.sinh(Math.PI)) * 180 / Math.PI;

function initialize() {

    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    // DOM event listener for the center map form submit
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('mapCenterForm'), 'submit', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        // Get lat and lng values from input fields
        var lat = document.getElementById('lat').value;
        var lng = document.getElementById('lng').value;

        // Validate user input as numbers
        lat = (!isNumber(lat) ? 0 : lat);
        lng = (!isNumber(lng) ? 0 : lng);

        // Validate user input as valid lat/lng values
        lat = latRange(lat);
        lng = lngRange(lng);

        // Replace input values
        document.getElementById('lat').value = lat;
        document.getElementById('lng').value = lng;

        // Create LatLng object
        var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

        new google.maps.Marker({

            position: mapCenter,
            title: 'Marker title',
            map: map
        });

        // Center map
        map.setCenter(mapCenter);
    });
}

function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function latRange(n) {
    return Math.min(Math.max(parseInt(n), -maxLat), maxLat);
}

function lngRange(n) {
    return Math.min(Math.max(parseInt(n), -180), 180);
}

initialize();
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/gefg183r/)</kbd>

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine i am trying to use mine to do nearly the same however with a marker,   so that i can input the values and place a marker there... can i use those boxes as well for this particular use?

Comment: Yes. I have updated the fiddle & code. It now centers the map and also adds a marker. FYI I have modified the DOM event listener so that it listens to the form submit instead of the button click (means you can hit enter in a form field instead of clicking the submit button...).

Comment: once again thanks for your help i will try to make mine the same as yours now that i have a good example to understand.