# Are Google Maps max bounds inconsistent with max latitude?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Just read this [SO's topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849636/maximum-lat-and-long-bounds-for-the-world-google-maps-api-latlngbounds) and found out the maximum bounds are not corresponding to the maximum possible values of latitude (which are [+90, -90] [according to Google Maps API][2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng)).

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(90, 0);
bounds.extend(latlng);
console.log(bounds.getNorthEast().toString()); // (90, 0)
```

So is it possible to display a map with the NorthEast point latitude set to 90 ? (It's the case in my app and that doesn't seem to work well... not 100% sure this is the problem but when I set it manually to less than 85, it works fine).

Or am I misunderstanding something ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe some more information on how to get the min/max latitude here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27115480/1238965

Comment: So not all the LatLng we can create are correct LatLng for LatLngBounds ? I understand the underlying theory (mercator projection) but I'm surprised there is no test on the value you pass to the LatLngBounds constructor.

Comment: I tried to come up with an answer. Interesting question btw :-) don't know why you got down+close-voted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is more information about the Mercator projection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27115480/1238965

Looking at the documentation about [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#LatLngBounds) it says:

> A LatLngBounds instance represents a rectangle in geographical coordinates, including one that crosses the 180 degrees longitudinal meridian.

So there is no mention about the latitude.

Looking at the [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#LatLng) class:

> A LatLng is a point in geographical coordinates: latitude and longitude.
>
> - Latitude ranges between -90 and 90 degrees, inclusive. **Values above or below this range will be clamped to the range [-90, 90]**. This means that if the value specified is less than -90, it will be set to -90. And if the value is greater than 90, it will be set to 90.
> - Longitude ranges between -180 and 180 degrees, inclusive. Values above or below this range will be wrapped so that they fall within the range. For example, a value of -190 will be converted to 170. A value of 190 will be converted to -170. This reflects the fact that longitudes wrap around the globe.

Also note that the constructor takes an optional third parameter:

`LatLng(lat:number, lng:number, noWrap?:boolean)`

> Latitude is specified in degrees within the range [-90, 90]. Longitude is specified in degrees within the range [-180, 180]. **Set `noWrap` to `true` to enable values outside of this range**.

So you can give the `LatLng` class values that are out of the normal range and they will be kept like that if you set the `nowrap` parameter to `true` but use them to construct a `LatLngBounds` object and they will be converted back to the [-90, 90] range.

Comment: 'they will be converted back to the [-90, 90] range' which seems to be a problem : LatLngBounds are not valid (at least you cannot display a map having those bounds) if you pass points whose latitude is not within the range [-85, +85]

Comment: Well... they are valid, but can't be displayed on a mercator projection.