# How Google Maps API calculates meters with coordinates?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I found this issue while experimenting with shapes. As written in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#circle_add), we can draw circle with `radius` specified in meters. But Google Maps <strike>use cylindrical projection of the Earth</strike> (edit: ok, it doesn't), so logically, in Arctic regions our circles should be something similar to ellipse. So I conducted simple experiment and drew a circle near The Egde. That's the result:

[image]

As we can see, we still have a circle.

So, my question is, how Google Maps API calculates meters? Is there some constant coefficient between meters and coordinates, used consequently? Or maybe this is a bug and in all other cases one meter in Google Maps equals one meter in reality?

Comment: Make that Circle draggable and drag it from north to south and see what happens...

Comment: Btw. the projection used is [EPSG:3857](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/EPSG:3857) or Spherical Mercator.

Comment: Ok, my mistake, I assumed that "The Edge" equals pole, but as I can see, pole is much much higher. Thanks :)

Comment: True. The edges are not at 90/-90. You can read more in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107440/unable-to-set-a-latlngbounds-with-longitude-from-180-to-0/27115480#27115480

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I said in comment, the problem was my misinterpretation of the north edge of the map. When it comes to measuring, **Google Maps API is reliable**. This is how my 400-meters circle looks like near the real north pole:

[image]