# Pass gmaps infowindow value to form

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, bootstrap-modal

Beginner here- I created a gmap with 2 markers (restaurants I like). Each marker has an infowindow with a button that opens a modal form. The form contains a input with id `textinput-2` that I would like to 'prepopulate' with the restaurant name.

Here's my javascript:

```
var issuebutton =
  '<!-- Button trigger modal -->'
  +'<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary  shadow-none" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#issueModal">'
  +'Report an issue'
  +'</button>'
;

var markersOnMap = [{Name: "Restaurant A", LatLng:[{lat: 40.729915, lng: -74.000264}]},{Name: "Restaurant B", LatLng:[{lat: 40.682579, lng: -73.993147}]}]

function addMarkerInfo() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markersOnMap.length; i++) {
      var contentString = '<div><b>'+markersOnMap[i].Name+'</b><br>'+issuebutton;
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: markersOnMap[i].LatLng[0],
            map: map,
            icon: './images/marker.png'
        });

        const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString,
        });

        marker.addListener('click', function () {
            closeOtherInfo();
            infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
            InforObj[0] = infowindow;
        });
    };
}

function closeOtherInfo() {
    if (InforObj.length > 0) {
        InforObj[0].set("marker", null);
        InforObj[0].close();
        InforObj.length = 0;
    }
}

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 14,
        center: {lat: 40.710848, lng: -73.9677},
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,;
}
```

The restaurant name populates perfect in the infowindow using `markersOnMap[i].Name` but `textinput-2` of my form is blank.

Here's the form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="issueModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="issueModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
            <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Restaurant Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="textinput-2" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
                </div>
            </div>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I think I have to use the below snippet, but I'm not sure where to place within my code:

```
document.getElementById('textinput-2').value = markersOnMap[i].Name;
```

Comment: There seems to be some code missing? I don't see anywhere there is "_a button that opens a modal form_" in your `google.maps.InfoWindow`. Basically though, you would put the code to populate that input in the `click` handler that opens the modal.

Comment: sorry about that- added now (the button is 'issuebutton' which is included in 'contentstring' )

Comment: Learn how to provide a [mcve]. We don't need/want a link to your website where the content will change as we try to help. What you provided is not minimal nor complete.

Comment: appreciate the tip- what's best practice for creating gmaps-related minimal reproducible examples where an api key is required? generate a new key for the example then delete once question has been answered?

Comment: Don't put your key. Provide a code snippet without the key. This can easily be copied to an answer where I can add a working key. Or you can use `AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk` which is a key that Google allowed for use on stacksnippets and jsfiddle sites. Or, find an answer like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58769407/1238965) which contains a working google maps code snippet, hit the *Copy snippet to answer* button and copy all the code generated (don't post it...) you can then paste it in your question and you will have a working Google Maps API snippet. Adapt it. Done.

Comment: @michaelscarn I appologize. I missed the part that this was a bootstrap project, as such the button and modal are tied together by that library. I'm not overly familiar with that library, I don't use it myself. In any case depending on what bootstrap makes available, you're looking to either attach a function to the click event of the button or attach a function to the "open" event of the modal (if it exists and whatever bootstrap calls it). Inside that function is where  you would modify the contents of the modal.

Comment: @gforce301 that sounds complicated... If, as I suppose, the modal code is in the HTML of the page where the Google Maps code is included, then the text input could be populated right from the marker click listener. No matter if the modal is shown / will show or not. That said, the question, as it is, is incomplete and hard to answer.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Good point. As such, there is everything he needs in his post. He has the marker click handler shown in code. Do you want to write up the answer?

Comment: With the above comments OP should be able to solve it by himself. I'd wait for the question to contain a [mcve] before providing an answer.